# Send Persian string from C# server to python client with socket

Tags: c#, python, sockets, encode

I use socket programming to connect a python program to a C# program.
python code is client and C# code is server. C# code send a string to python with this code:

```
byte[] R=Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("one string");
Client.Send(R);
```

and i receive data in python code with this:

```
data=sock.recv(16)
amount_received+=len(data)
print >> sys.stderr, 'received "%s" %data
```

When i print recieved data: `print >> sys.stderr, 'received "%s" %data` , I just see some question marks. 
what must I do?

Comment: You have to `decode()` it. use `data.decode()`

Comment: @AminEtesamian, i tested decode(), but it didn't work

Comment: it still shows question marks?

Comment: try `GetBytes("some english input")` to see if the problem relates to Farsi or something else

Comment: when i tested English string that work correctly. but in Persian just print question marks.

Comment: or try
`byte[] R = Encoding.Default.GetBytes("Persian String");`
`myString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(R);`
`Client.Send(myString);'

Comment: is data coming in `????` or is it showing in the console as `????`?

Comment: what is type of "myString" variable?when i set string type for "myString " i have an error in 'Client.Send(myString);'.

Comment: when i print data in console, i see ???

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125324/discussion-between-amin-etesamian-and-narges).

Comment: When i use just "byte[] R = Encoding.Default.GetBytes("Persian String"); Client.Send(R);" work correctly. thanks a lot @Amin Etesamian.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
byte[] R = Encoding.Default.GetBytes("Persian String");
```